# a href javascript post

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

```
<a href="javascript:$.post(' bla bla bla ..
```

данный сверху код отправляет пост запрос при клике на ссылку, на всех браузерах все корректно работает, но в мозиле открывается вот такая вот вкладка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как решить проблему?

Comment: Для начала показать полный код ссылки.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал такого типа запросы не делать. А оформить как отдельную функцию и прицепить ее на onclick, который редиректит (или реагирует) на то, что посылает ваш post.

Comment: зачем полный код? код работает на всех браузерах кроме мозиллы, не в коде дело

Answer (score 3, accepted):

лучше использовать onclick он работает везде правильно.

```
<a href="#post" onclick="$.post(' bla bla bla');return false;">post...</a>
```

в конце чтоб хэш не срабатывал надо добавить

```
return false;
```